# textarea limit to 250 words jquery

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Hi is there a way to limit the words in textarea having the same function as **maxlength** do using jquery or coffeescript and with the use of keyup function as well because I need to display an accurate counter. I've been searching around but can't find a way to do this. I've tried this but it is on keypress and it's allowing the user to paste more than 250 words.

```
  $(document).on "keypress", '#company_desc', (e) ->
    s = $("#company_desc").val()
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "")
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, " ")
    s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n")
    count = s.split(" ").length
    $(".counter").html(250 - count + " words remaining")
    if count == 250
      key = (if e.charCode then e.charCode else (if e.keyCode then e.keyCode else 0))
      switch key
        when e.ctrlKey && key == keys[CTRL_A] then return true
        when e.ctrlKey && key == keys[CTRL_C] then return true
        when e.ctrlKey && key == keys[CTRL_X] then return true
        when e.ctrlKey && key == keys[CTRL_Z] then return true
        else return key == 46 || key == 8
```

Comment: What is `array of keys` in `keys[CTRL_A]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your textarea add attr "maxlength"

try this.

```
$("your textarea id and class").attr("maxlength", 250);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Here's my code now and it works perfectly - [limit words in textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/melwee/RULWW/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxWords = 150;
jQuery('textarea').keypress(function() {
var $this, wordcount;
$this = $(this);
wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
if (wordcount > maxWords) {
    jQuery(".word_count span").text("" + maxWords);
    alert("You've reached the maximum allowed words.");
    return false;
} else {
    return jQuery(".word_count span").text(wordcount);
}
});
```

fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/qPvch/164/

Comment: thanks! but it still allows the user to paste more than the max word. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this.

```
var maxWords = 250;
jQuery('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var a, wordcount;
    a = $(this).val();
    a = a.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
    a = a.replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, " ");
    a = a.replace(/\n /, "\n");
    wordcount = a.split(" ").length;
    if (wordcount == maxWords) {
        $(this).val(a.substr(0, a.length));
    }
    if (wordcount > maxWords) {
        $(this).val(a.substr(0, a.length - 1));
    }
    return jQuery(".word_count span").text(maxWords - wordcount + " words remaining");
});
$('textarea').bind("paste",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I used `.substr(0, a.length -1)` to cut off the words and to force the user to remain inside the maxWords, I also disabled pasting inside the textarea (this disables also right-click paste) but i don't think this is the best way, it is better if the user can still use *paste* and automatically cut the excess words after pasting or disable it when user already reached the max word like the `maxlength` do. Any suggestions?
Here's my fiddle - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melwee/RULWW/4/)